# How do I add more than 1 item to Cart at a time when add to cart button is clicked

Tags: javascript, cart

I am having trouble adding more than one item to cart at a time when the add to cart button is clicked. The alert I have set up for it shows the correct quantity but it only adds 1 item at a time to the actual cart.

Here is the code:

```js
const quantity = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

    for (let i in quantity) {
        const optionQuantity = document.createElement('option');
        optionQuantity.innerHTML = quantity[i];
        optionQuantity.setAttribute('value', quantity[i]);
        dropDownOptionsQuantity.appendChild(optionQuantity);
    }
```

```js
addToCart.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let cartItems = [];
        const localStorageContent = localStorage.getItem('cart');
        if (localStorageContent === null) {
            cartItems = [];
        } else {
            cartItems = JSON.parse(localStorageContent);
        }
        let product = {
            imageUrl: response.imageUrl,
            name: response.name,
            id: response._id,
            price: response.price,
            selectColors: dropdownOptionsColors.value,
            quantity: parseInt(dropDownOptionsQuantity.value)
        };
        cartItems.push(product);
        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));

        addNumCart();
    });
```

```js
function addNumCart() {
    const localStorageContent = localStorage.getItem('cart');
    if (localStorageContent) {
        let cartItemsArray = JSON.parse(localStorageContent);
        let cartItemsTotal = document.querySelector('.cartItemsTotal');
        cartItemsTotal.innerHTML = cartItemsArray.length;
    }
}
addNumCart();
```

Comment: You can add one more item to local storage via different key.For example window. localStorage.setItem('newkey');

Comment: I hope this will help you

Comment: Gulshan Aggarwal  Thank You, I need to rephrase the question not add to local storage but add to cart. When the button is clicked the quantity only adds 1 item at a time regardless of how many are selected.

Comment: You seem to be using the length of the array as the quantity, but you're storing it as a property of the item. You need to check the quantity property.

Comment: SOLVED: It seems like I was only adding one item at a time to the cart because I only created one product object based on the user's selection of color and quantity, and then pushed that single object into the cartItems array.

To add multiple items to the cart, I used a loop to create a new product object for each item and then push each object into the cartItems array.